# Authorize.net - Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) & Address Verification Services (AVS)

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing

I have setup Authorize.net's Automated Recurring Billing in a system I have built, which works great.

The only downfall is when someone puts in bad billing information, AVS is not checked (and it returns successful). It only creates the account, and the payment will fail at the first time it is billed, which is often the next day.

How can I catch the bad billing information *before* we complete the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AIM to process the first payment. That way you know the card is valid before setting up the subscription and can perform AVS and CVV verification. If you don't want to charge the first payment, then do an AUTH_ONLY with AIM to accomplish the same effect.